# alert view buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, button, xcode4.3, uialertview

I'm creating an iOS application and when the score reaches 100 this alert will show and it all work fine but the buttons (share,apple,rate this app).

```
     - (void) buttonAction {
                counter++;
                if(counter == 100)
                    [self showAlert];
            }

            - (void) showAlert {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                                      initWithTitle:@"hello"
                                      message:@"whats you name" 
                                      delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"share", @"apple" , @"rate this app", nil]; 


 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if (buttonIndex == 0) { // means share button pressed
            // write your code here to do whatever you want to do once the share button is pressed
        }
        if(buttonIndex == 1) { // means apple button pressed
            // write your code here to do whatever you want to do once the apple button is pressed
        }
        // and so on for the last button
    }

                [alert show];



            }

            -(IBAction)plus {
                counter=counter + 1;
                count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
                if(counter == 100)
                    [self showAlert];

            }

            -(IBAction)zero {
                counter=0;
                count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
            }



        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            counter=0;
            count.text = @"0";
                [super viewDidLoad];

        }
```

what i would like to no where do i add the link etc. thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @PrasadG just a method really on how i can make the buttons (apple etc go to the apple site for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following...

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                      initWithTitle:@"hello"
                      message:@"whats you name" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"share", @"apple" , @"rate this app", nil]; 

[alert show];
```

and then add the following method in your code:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
      if (buttonIndex == 0) { // means share button pressed
              // write your code here to do whatever you want to do once the share button is pressed
      }
      if(buttonIndex == 1) { // means apple button pressed
              // write your code here to do whatever you want to do once the apple button is pressed
      }
      // and so on for the last button
 }
```

one advise, you might get more helpful answers if you were more clear in your question what exactly you wanted to do...

hope it helps

Comment: I've just added it in and i get the following error: use of undeclared identifier 'alertView' did you mean UIAlertView?  and thanks for the advice i will keep that in mind and also where do i add http://www.apple.com thank you

Comment: and I've edited my answer thats where i put your code look up

Comment: i edited your code now it should work... feel free to mark my answer as correct once it work for you ;)

Comment: -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

this is a separate method, dont put it in the showAlert method...

Comment: ok thats work now do you no where i add the http://www.apple.com thanks and your answer is marked :)

Comment: you can use something like the following within the if clauses:


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that, you need a method for identifying which alert button is pressed by the user. For that you can use this delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

}
```

Inside this method, you need to check the button index that was pressed by the user.
And according to that, you can do the other stuffs.

For using the delegate method, you need to set the `delegate` of alert view to `self`

For further reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) method: `– alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`
Set your controller as the UIAlertViewDelegate when you init it, then inside your implementation of `– alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`, call the various methods pertaining to the relevant button index.